# Optical Property calculation in VASP using HSE

Tags: vasp, optical-properties, hse06

I have calculated frequency-dependent dielectric constant in VASP using PBE exchange-correlation functional, within the framework of Independent particle approximation (with RPA). I want to perform the same calculation using HSE.
I have seen a lot of examples and tutorials for Band structure calculation with HSE but could not find a step-by-step procedure for the optical property with HSE.
If any expert can give a set of INCAR files for the same I will remain grateful.

Comment: Could be off base because I don't use VASP, but can't you just change the functional to HSE and leave everything else the same from the PBE calculation?

Comment: I think there are problems with hybrid functionals and RPA, do read the literature before pursuing this.

Comment: This question seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or if someone would like to provide an answer.